# Trying to port recursive JavaScript method to C#, does this approach make sense?

Tags: c#, javascript, recursion

The method in JavaScript is:

```
findNode: function(root, w, h) {
    if (root.used)
        return this.findNode(root.right, w, h) || this.findNode(root.down, w, h);
    else if ((w <= root.w) && (h <= root.h))
        return root;
    else
        return null;
}
```

this line in particular wont work in C#

```
return this.findNode(root.right, w, h) || this.findNode(root.down, w, h);
```

This is my attempt at translating it but I could use a second opinion as to whether this will work or break the algorithm. Is there a better way that I'm missing?

```
private Node FindNode(Node node, Block block)
{
    Node n;
    if (node.used) // recursive case
    {

        // is this a good translation of the JavaScript one-liner?

        n = FindNode(node.right, block);
        if (n != null)
        {
            return n;
        }
        else
        {
            return FindNode(node.down, block);
        }
    }
    else if ((block.width <= node.width) && (block.height <= node.height)) // Base case
    {
        return node;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

[Here is the original algorithm I'm working off of.](https://github.com/jakesgordon/bin-packing/blob/master/js/packer.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = FindNode(node.right, block);
return n ?? FindNode(node.down, block);
```

would be the only change I would make

Comment: @ Kirk Woll Apparently this `return FindNode(node.right, block) ?? FindNode(node.down, block);` compiles fine. Is that what I'm looking for? Thanks, learned a new operator today.

Comment: @pdizz, yes, `??` has the same semantic meaning as `||` in Javascript in this particular scenario.  (this is because in Javascript you can use the boolean `||` operator with any type and a null value is `false`)